# Fetching images from api and displaying them in UIImageView swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimageview

I am trying to fetch images from an API  and display them in an `UITableView` using Swift.

I managed to fetch all the properties accurately but I might not be doing error handling in the event that there is no image for a particular object i.e. restaurant. This is because the table view starts to populate fine with some images and then bombs out with the following error:

> **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

Please look at my implementation and let me know if I could change anything.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {

   if let image =  UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: self.restaurants[indexPath.row].restaurantImage)!)!) {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
                cell.restaurantImage.image = image
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely you are trying to access to an optional when its value is `nil`, you need to make first an optional binding to check if the possible values you're trying to access are not `nil`.

According to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/initWithString:) the constructor of the `NSURL` `init(string:)`:

> Returns an `NSURL` object initialized with `URLString`. If the URL string was malformed, returns `nil`.

So then you need to do the following in first place:

```
if let url = NSURL(string: self.restaurants[indexPath.row].restaurantImage) {

}
```

Then the next optional is the contructor of the `UIImage` class that according to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/initWithString:):

> Returns an `NSURL` object initialized with `URLString`. If the URL string was malformed, returns `nil`. So then you need to do the following code instead:

```
if let url = NSURL(string: self.restaurants[indexPath.row].restaurantImage) {
   if let image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: url)) {
   }
}
```

And finally you should the same for the failable constructor of the `NSData` class which can return `nil` too, and your final code should be like the following:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {

     if let url = NSURL(string: self.restaurants[indexPath.row].restaurantImage) {
         if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
             if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
                     cell.restaurantImage.image = image
                 }
             }
         }
     }
})
```

Always you use the `!` operator over an optional you're saying to the compiler that you know that the value it's not `nil`, it's better use optional-chaining to assure that the variable it's not `nil`.

I hope this help you.

Comment: @user2610863 Glad to help you